# How to access an enum variant's field without explicitly binding it during match?

Tags: rust

Lets say I have an enum `E`, that might be auto-generated or outside of my control, with many variants and each variant having a number of fields.

```rust
enum E {
    A {
        x1: u8,
        x2: u8,
        x3: u8,
        // ...
        x9: u8,
    },
    B,
}
```

In reality the fields might be longer and neither nice to remember, nor nice to type.

I now want to write functions that operate on (variants of) `E`. However, I am also lazy, **and I don't want to repeat myself, *declaring* each used field explicitly when destructuring the enum***.

Intuitively I would have expected the binding operator `@` to do the job here, but it only binds the whole enum `e`, not the given variant `E::A`.

What is the shortest / most elegant way to achieve the following intention?

```rust
fn f(e: &E) {
    match e {
        bad @ E::A { .. } => dbg!(bad.x1),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

---

***Update** since this has been brought up in two answers already, I do **not** want to match with `E::A { x1, .. }`, as this gets tedious when needing multiple fields with long names. In the example below, I would have to type out `some_other_field_with_an_impossibly_long_name` twice in my own code (once when binding it, once when using it), whereas in the hypothetical `bad @ E::A` case I'd have to type it out only once.

```rust
match e {
    E::A { some_field_with_a_long_name, some_other_field_with_an_impossibly_long_name, yet_another_field, .. } => dbg!(some_other_field_with_an_impossibly_long_name),
    _ => {}
}
```

Comment: Maybe a hint that this will not work: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40666 .

Comment: Hah, thanks! I think this is the actual _answer_ to this problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the following could help:

```
fn f(e: &E) {
  match e {
   E::A {x1, .. } => {dbg!(x1);},
    _ => {}
  };
}
```

`E::A {x1,..}` is short for `bad @ E::A {x1:x1, ..}` and binds the value of `bad.x1` to a new local variable `x1` that is available in the body scope.

Comment: Thanks, however as stated in my question, I do _not_ want to bind `x1`, ... explicitly.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I misinterpreted your statement. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a macro with variadic args, so **the compiler** does the typing long names twice, and it binds as many as parameters you need. You may call your function inside the macro instead of println:

```
    f!(&e, x1);
    f!(&e, x2, x1);
```

```
macro_rules! f {
    ($e: expr, $( $name:ident ),+ ) => {
        match $e {
            E::A {   $($name),* , ..} => {
                println!("{:?}", &[$($name),*]); // call your function here.
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    };
}
```

Try it on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=569c5fc4d8f360dad92665beb9e3055c)